# url referrer problem in gmail

Tags: c#, url, gmail, referrer

I am getting Url referer in global asax file.

```
 try
    {
        if (Session["url"] == null && !Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().StartsWith("http://www.mydomain") && !Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().StartsWith("http://mydomain"))
            Session["Url"] = Request.UrlReferrer;
    }
    catch { }
```

Its working, but if the url in gmail dosent work. How canI get Url Referrer from gmail?
Thanks

Comment: Define "doesn't work." Is there no referrer at all? If there is, what is it? Also note that you can't control from your server application whether or not a client browser sends the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

If by "doesn't work" you mean that you are getting a null value then that is because URLReferrer header is not sent for SSL requests and Gmail uses SSL. This is intended - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3